# WCF Service Error on Client Service Test - SVCUtil

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-client, service-reference

I created a WCF service which compiles fine and published ok; I created a web app to test the WCF service and initially when using `svcutil.exe` it created the source file but not the config file. So I added the service as a service reference and that looked fine until I tried to run the client app. The following error showed up:

```
Could not find default endpoint element that 
references contract 'ServiceReference1.IService1' in the ServiceModel 
client configuration section. This might be because no configuration 
file was found for your application, or because no endpoint 
element matching this contract could be found in the client element.
```

I figured its something wrong with the web.config file and searching for posts I found that I needed to copy the service model section from the service config file to the client test web config file. This did not help.

#### WCF Service config file

```
<configuration>

<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="webHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
 </behaviors>
  <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" name="WcfInstanceRules2.Service1">
    <endpoint address="mex" 
     binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding"      

    contract="WcfInstanceRules2.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
  </service>
 </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

#### WebApp Test Config file

```xml
    <configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices"
    connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices"
             enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
             maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
             applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
      </providers>
    </profile>
     <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.serviceModel>
     <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
     <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="webHttpBinding" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
      </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webHttpBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
       <services>
       <service behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" name="WcfInstanceRules2.Service1">
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="webHttpBinding"   
     bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" 
     contract="WcfInstanceRules2.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
      </service>
     </services>
     </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a **client endpoint** defined on the client side. You are currently defining a new service host on the web app. On the client side, you should have something like...

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
  <client>
     <endpoint address="http://.../mex" binding="webHttpBinding"   
 bindingConfiguration="webHttpBinding" 
 contract="ServiceReference1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior"/>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

To make this easier, VS.NET will add this client endpoint for you when you use **[Add Service Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb628652.aspx)**.

Comment: thanks for your response. The problem is that when I tried to Add a Service Reference, the web.config file did not get updated in the client app just as when using svcutil did not create a config file either.

Answer (score 0):

In your endpoint tag change contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"

where ServiceReference1 is service refference which you add in your project.